# Summernote get selected text and had class

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

How to get the selected text when i click on the button and add class with summernote and custom button.

```
     var HelloButton = function (context) {
                var ui = $.summernote.ui;

                // create button
                var button = ui.button({
                    contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Hello',
                    tooltip: 'hello',
                    click: function (event) {

//                        Here my selected text
                        value = "My selected text";

//                        Here add balise and class
                        value = '<h1 class="myClass">+value+</h1>';

//                        Here modify textarea
                        context.invoke('editor.insertText', value);
                    }
                });

                return button.render();   // return button as jquery object
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change click to:

```
click: function() {

    var text = context.invoke('editor.getSelectedText'); // HERE IS YOUR SELECTED TEXT

    var $node = $('<h1 class="YOUR_CLASS">'+text+'<h1>');

    context.invoke('editor.insertNode', $node[0]);
}
```

Comment: `editor.getSelectedText` only returns the selected text (as it should be), not the underlying element/node.